# select column based on date interval converted from unix timestamp in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, unix-timestamp

I have to run a select from table based on a condition from a column with a unix timestamp value. I have converted the value into a date in order to apply my condition. The query is something along the lines:

```
select col1,
col2,
col3,
from table 
where trunc(to_date('01.01.1970', 'dd.mm.yyyy') + numtodsinterval(create_date,'SECOND')) BETWEEN '01.12.2023' and '31.12.2023'
```

The problem is that when i run the query i get the
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"

I cannot figure out why and where is the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably on the right-hand side of the comparison with `BETWEEN '01.12.2023' and '31.12.2023'` and not the left. `'01.12.2023'` and `'31.12.2023'` are string literals and are **NOT** date data-types.

Either:

- use `DATE` literals:

  ```sql
  BETWEEN DATE '2023-12-01' AND DATE '2023-12-31'
  ```
- or explicitly convert the strings to dates using `TO_DATE`:

  ```sql
  BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.12.2023', 'DD.MM.YYYY') and TO_DATE('31.12.2023', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  ```

Alternatively, you can convert the right-hand side to a unix timestamp:

```sql
WHERE create_date >= (DATE '2023-12-01' - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60
AND   create_date <  (DATE '2024-01-01' - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Which would let you use an index on the `create_date` column.